# my brush setup got destroyed when open in node graph

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

i'm in texture paint mode and i created a new texture brush, so i click '+' and name it 'stars'. Then i go to far right panel, in the texture tab, i open my new created brush and change type to "Marble". The problem is when i now go to node editor and try to load my brush nodes, everytime i turn ON 'use Nodes' , rather than loading my current selected brush setup, it destroyed my brush and reset to the checker one. Is it a bug ? or did i do something wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: Share some screen shots for reference so we can see what you are meaning.

Answer (score 0):

The Texture Nodes Editor is pretty useful if you are working with making brushes except that it isn't safe when setting up a brush before enabling nodes. Pretty much all the time I use it, I set up the brush in the node editor before adding anything in the texture stack. The default when starting is the red and white checkered node, and from there you can add what you want and build a pretty complicated setup - but if you try to nodify your existing brush, it will negate all the previous effort, so start in the node editor if that is what you want.

You don't normally need to though unless you are combining procedurals together as a single brush/brush mask.

Edit: For 2.80 beta, we have seen this node system removed for now. There are possibilities after Everything Nodes is worked on that we will see and even more robust system for manipulating texture brushes with nodes and using them in the texture paint system.